# If $R$ is a commutative ring with ideal $I$, $a \in R$; implications of $I + Ra$ being finitely generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, finitely-generated

$R$ is a commutative ring with $I \lhd R, a \in R$
If $I + Ra$ is finitely generated, I want to show that this implies that $\exists$ finitely generated $J \subseteq I$ finitely generated with $J + Ra = I + Ra$.

I have been attempting to prove this for a while now, as I have used it to prove that if every prime ideal of $R$ is finitely generated then $R$ is necessarily Noetherian; but embarrassingly I can't seem to get this first statement.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: There's nothing embarrassing in not being able to prove something ;)

Comment: An element from $I+Ra$ has the form $i+ra$ with $i\in I$ and $r\in R$. If this ideal is finitely generated then there are finitely many elements of the form $i_k+r_ka$ that generate $I+Ra$. Set $J$ the ideal generated by all $i_k$.

Comment: Of Course, thanks!